# Loop through lines in a text file and parse matching information Python

Tags: python, regex, text

I have a text file that I need to loop through each line and only extract certain matching information. The text file has many lines as below:

```
person       loan amount    1 month past due     2 month pass due
-------    ---------------  -----------------   -------------------
Tom          3000              3000                  0.00
1365                           100.00%               0.00%
...
...
```

I need  to combine two lines to have results as below:

```
['1365', 'Tom']
```

Below is how I attempted it:

```
with open(filepath) as f:
count=0
for line in f:
    if line.find("----") == -1 and line != '\n' and re.research("person|loan amount|pass due",line) == None:
           l=parse_line(line)
           combine=l
           combine.append(l)
```

Below is the function:

```
def parse_line(strIn):
    temp=strIn.rsplit(' ',1)
    out=[]
    out=[temp[0].strip()
return out
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You may bypass the 2 header lines, then read the file 2-lines by 2, this can be done with `zip`

```
filepath = r"file.txt"
result = []
with open(filepath) as fic:
    lines = fic.readlines()[2:]  # remove header lines
    for name_line, value_line in zip(lines[::2], lines[1::2]):
        name = name_line.split(" ")[0]
        value = value_line.split(" ")[0]
        result.append((value, name))

print(result)  # [('1365', 'Tom'), ('1246', 'Linda')]
```

Comment: Problem I have is  my text file is a big file and have a lot of other junk that hard to identify where to slice. So i used regex  and conditional function to identify where to start. The problem is it only process one line at a  time , for example, i get Tom first then next loop will get 1365, I tried append or concat, all I got is none...